# problem while deploying react application to github

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, npm, command-prompt

I created a todolist that is working properly in localhost.
Iam trying to deploy it on github, when I run '$ npm run deploy' in command propmt it showing error  p

Added homepage, predeploy, deploy properties to package.json

installed gh-pages --save-dev

Please help I am a beginner

This is the command prompt error.

```
    
C:\Users\Syed\Desktop\project\todolist>npm run deploy

> todolist@0.1.0 predeploy C:\Users\Syed\Desktop\project\todolist
> npm run build


> todolist@0.1.0 build C:\Users\Syed\Desktop\project\todolist
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.

./src/App.js
  Line 2:8:    'logo' is defined but never used              no-unused-vars
  Line 52:20:  Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

File sizes after gzip:

  55.54 KB  build\static\js\2.0512a152.chunk.js
  1.19 KB   build\static\js\main.1e3fd05a.chunk.js
  785 B     build\static\js\runtime-main.ce724f51.js
  657 B     build\static\css\main.362672fb.chunk.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /To-Do-List/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.

Find out more about deployment here:

  bit.ly/CRA-deploy


> todolist@0.1.0 deploy C:\Users\Syed\Desktop\project\todolist
> gh-pages -d build

fatal: A branch named 'gh-pages' already exists.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! todolist@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the todolist@0.1.0 deploy script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Syed\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-02T01_49_57_997Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this quickstart [guide](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/quickstart)
You will need to set up the GitHub pages homepage link on your GitHub repository settings page first.
Then check the source as well.
Then save. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue with

```
fatal: A branch named 'gh-pages' already exists.
```

remove the '**gh-pages/**' folder at ***node_modeules/.cache/***

This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I am not professional in react and these tools.

But error log states that you already have a branch named "gh-pages" check your github repository and delete it.

Answer (score -1):

You would find [this](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/react-modern-library-boilerplate/issues/15) if you've searched a little bit.

Delete `node_modules/gh-pages/.cache` and try again.

Linux / macOS / Git bash: `rm -rf node_modules/gh-pages/.cache`